# How to insert columns in between in table in sql server 2008

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I want to add or update columns using alter table if i am adding a new column i want show error. I am using the code below

```
 alter table Personal_Details alter columns DOB datetime
```

if i uncheck the NULL to not NULL then it will shows column does not allow nulls; update fails;

i want to insert the fields in between columns not at end.

Plese fix my bug,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to ALTER or ADD a column? And are you doing this against a live database?

Comment: ur update statement gives no clue as to what u are trying to do...
can u paste the create code of your table as well

Comment: What do you mean by insert fields in between cols? Surely it is of no consequence to you how the fields appear in the table definition?

Comment: @BonyT I am trying to ALTER the columns only. Yes i am doing against the live database

Comment: @Mulki : Sorry partner i am just alter the column name and the column insert into in between the other columns. But when i am altering the column it comes to end of the table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The position of the column in the table declaration has nothing to do with its being NULL or NOT NULL.

If you are adding a column (of any type) which you want to be NOT NULL, i.e. you want to prohibit NULL values in that column, *and* the table already contains some rows, you *must* also provide some default value. For example:

```
ALTER TABLE Personal_Details
ADD COLUMN DOB datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT (GETDATE())
```

Otherwise the engine will attempt to add that column with NULLs as its values, which will violate the NOT NULL property, and the change, therefore, will be reverted.

Basically, the same applies when you want to set an *existing* column's NOT NULL property on while the column already contains NULLs. But in this case you must explicitly eliminate the NULLs before the change by either replacing them with values or removing the respective rows.

Source:

- [ALTER TABLE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx). (The particular section related to your problem is just above [this code snippet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx#CodeSpippet2).)

Answer (score 0):

1)For ur adding column with not null problem

Use

```
ALTER TABLE Personal_Details ADD COLUMN DOB datetime NULL
```

Update the DOB column with the required dates and make sure there is no null in the column
then alter the column using

```
ALTER TABLE Personal_Details ALTER COLUMN DOB datetime not NULL
```

2)For your column going to the end problem...

1. you should not be worried...the order in which the columns are arranged doesnt matter...unless u are using a pathetic way of accessing data by column order..in which case again..u should stop accessing it by column order...
2. If the column order really matters you can change it using design option in the sql management table(rightclick on table >design and drag the column to its required place.)